# Annotated Configuration usage with Spring Integration

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I have the following xml and I would like to replace this annoying xml with `@Configuration` class

```
<int:gateway id="someActionGateway "
        service-interface="x.y.z.SomeActionGateway"
        default-request-channel="some-action-channel-raw" />

 <int:channel id="some-action-channel-raw" />

 <int:header-enricher input-channel="some-action-channel-raw" output-channel="some-action-to-json-channel">
        <int:header name="someAction" value="sendSomething"/>
 </int:header-enricher>

    <int:channel id="some-action-to-json-channel" />

    <int:object-to-json-transformer
        input-channel="some-action-to-json-channel" output-channel="some-action-outbound-channel"
        content-type="text/x-json" />

    <int:channel id="some-action-outbound-channel" />

    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter
        channel="some-action-outbound-channel" exchange-name="some-action-exchange"
        routing-key="someAction.routing.key" amqp-template="amqpTemplate"
        mapped-request-headers="*">
    </int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>

    <rabbit:direct-exchange name="some-action-exchange"
        auto-delete="false" durable="true">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="some-action-queue" key="someAction.routing.key" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:direct-exchange>
```

and my gateway:

```
public interface SomeActionGateway {

    @Gateway
    public void sendSomething(@Payload SomeDto dto);

}
```

I'm already using configuration annotated class for spring-amqp and it just works fine.
 How can I do the same with Spring Integration configuration?

**P.S:** I'm using Spring 3.2 and Spring integration 3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sorry you find XML configuration "annoying".

We are working on improving the JavaConfig (`@Configuration`) experience for Spring Integration.

You can currently wire up any endpoint with JavaConfig today, but it's not pretty; endpoints can be wired with a `MessageDrivenConsumer` (or `PollingConsumer`) together with the appropriate `MessageHandler`. You would have to dig into the `ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean` and the XML parsers for full details; most components require more than one bean definition.

Like I said, we are working on it; we currently have an open [Pull Request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1055) for a gateway and there is a Java DSL underway [in the extensions repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/tree/master/spring-integration-java-dsl) but it is a work in process, as are the Scala and Groovy DSLs.

EDIT:

Spring Integration 4.0 makes it much easier to use `@Configuration`.

See the recent [webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3DgdSqEgzI&list=PLgGXSWYM2FpNmY5a1MuomSvvovSWHWoAR&index=7).